# Transfer files between host and guest using virtio-serial

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt, virtio

I have a Windows 10 guest with very limited network access (limited by Check-Point VPN firewall) which I access through the spice viewer.
 
But I need to transfer files to/from the guest.
I tried to setup Folder Sharing (a function of the virt remote spice viewer) but even that seemed to be blocked by the guest firewall (cannot access the webdavd service).
I assume my only option is to use the virtio-serial as this will not use network.
My first problem is to define a channel in the virt XML file:

```
<channel type='unix'>
   <source type='bind' path='/tmp/foo'/>
   <target type='virtio' port='0'/>
</channel>
```

But I get the error

```
error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng
Extra element devices in interleave
Element domain failed to validate content
```

Any help are appreciated.

Comment: I don't expect a "shared folder" functionality out-of-the box from using virtio-serial, I assume I need to make tool in both end to receive/send data to/from the virtio-serial interface. The above snippet was a copy from a google search

Comment: Are all of the standard ways of transferring files - Samba, FTP, SSH - being blocked?

Comment: Cannot use LAN network. VM is restricted to VPN network. But I can use cloud-storage which is was I've ended up doing although it's not pretty :-P
But it seems the Virtio-serial interface seem rather limited to a few MB/s so I guess that path is a no-go anyway. Maybe I could use an iSCSI block-device although there might be complications when two clients access the same drive. But it could be interesting to try.